# ON the field or IN the field?

Tags: prepositions, in-on-at

I am confused about the usage of preposition in this sentence:

> "They work hard ____ the field everyday".

What should fill the blank?
   a/ On
   b/ In

Answer (score 2):

The correct preposition here is *in*.

In cases like this, *the field* is a place or location, so the preposition is *in*.

> He works *in* a bakery.
>   She works *in* a bank.
>   They work *in* a bookshop.

When the object in the sentence is an object (a thing), then the preposition would be *on*.

> He works *on* computers.
>   She works *on* innovative projects.
>   They work *on* improving performance.

Comment: A quibble.  If "the field" is a playing field for a sporting event - so that 'they' are groundskeepers - then "on the field" would be correct.  Just as "I worked on the car".

Comment: @JohnFeltz What is your quibble? "I am a mechanic, I work on cars.", "I am a groundskeeper, I work on the playing field." Then the field is the object that is worked on, rather than describing a location. :-)